# How can dynamically add rows and columns in data frame in python using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

I have to input data from user for a few parameters like person_id, item_purchased, item_sold. item_purchased has sub-columns that need to be added as when the user purchases something and same applies for the item_sold.

[image: the data frame looks like this]

How can I add the no of rows and no of columns dynamically as and when the user inputs the data?

Comment: Would there always be one data frame that gets updated, or a new one created after every purchase?  Are you saying that as more and more product are purchased / sold, you'd enter in new columns in the existing data frame?

Comment: Yes, I'd be updating the existing data frame with the addition of new products for purchased/sold column.